# Lattice basis consisting of minimal vectors

Tags: integer-lattices

I have the following theorem that I would like to prove:

> Let $\Lambda$ be an $m$-dimensional Lattice of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then
> $\Lambda$ has a basis consisting of $b_1,...,b_m$ with $||b_j||= \lambda_j(\Lambda)$ for $1 \leq j \leq min(m,4)$ where $\lambda_j(\Lambda)$ denotes the $j$-th successive minima.

For smaller dimensions, however, I can only find examples that confirm the theorem. How would one prove something like this in general?

I think this is an interesting question that may be of interest to the community here.

Comment: What is $\lambda_j(\Lambda)$ here?

Comment: Hey, I just edited the post to that point. The $\lambda_j(\Lambda)$ describes the $j$-th successive minima.