Existence of a basis of lattice with successive minima norms
Is there an easy way to show that given a lattice $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ of full rank, exists a basis where each vector has norm $\lambda_i$ i.e the i-th successive minima ($\lambda_i(\Lambda)=inf \{\text{dim(span}( \Lambda \cap \overline{B}(0,r)) \geq i\})$?
The existence of such independent vectors is not a problem since the balls centered in $0$ of that radius are finite thanks to lattice definition.
My problem is that I don't how to show that those $\mathbb{Z}-$generate $\Lambda$. This claim could pass from the fact that something is a basis if and only if doesn't intersect the fundamental parallelepiped?
Any help or reference would be appreciated.

what do you mean by each vector being the $i$-th successive minima?

@AnCar I edited the question, sorry if was unclear.

It is not always possible to show that there exists a basis $B = [b_1, \dots, b_n]$ such that $|b_i| = \lambda_i(\Lambda)$. See the following post - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681308/a-problem-about-successive-minima-of-a-lattice-in-mathbbrn?rq=1

The answer in the following post shows that there exists a basis $B = [b_1, \dots, b_n]$ such that $|b_i| \leq max{1, \sqrt{i}/2} \cdot \lambda_i(\Lambda)$. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4532410/lattice-basis-consisting-of-minimal-vectors/4910717#4910717

@MaheshSR Why this implies that exists a basis such that $||b_i|| = \lambda_i$?

@jacopoburelli I guess I might have confused you with two separate comments. There is a theorem that states that for any lattice $\Lambda$ there exists a basis $B = [b_1, \dots, b_n]$ such that $|b_i| = max{1, \sqrt{i}/2} \cdot \lambda_i$. Observe for $n \leq 4$, this implies that $|b_i| = \lambda_i$. Whereas, for $n > 4$, we can find lattices such that there does not exist a basis with $|b_i| = \lambda_i$. An example for $n=5$ is given in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681308/a-problem-about-successive-minima-of-a-lattice-in-mathbbrn?rq=1 which can be easily extended.
